# How to generate a list of authors in a community that have published a thesis?

Tags: dspace

I'm using Dspace 7.6.1 and I'm looking to generate a list of all the authors who have uploaded a thesis in a community. I need this list to be sorted alphabetically by author and preferably available for download or copy. I've tried all the filters available in the UI and the advanced search. While I can retrieve a list of all the authors or thesis in a community, I don't know how to retrieve this specific list.

Could someone please advise me on the best way to accomplish this? Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!